# Even by setting maxMessagesPerPoll in camel JPA is there any way to retain my batch count

Tags: jpa, apache-camel

I was able to creating file with header,footer   based on camel index(0 means header) and batch complete(footer). Now if I  set the maxMessagesPerPoll=1000 for every 1000 records I am getting header and footer which means the camel batch index is set to zero. Now if I don't set maxMessagesPerPoll  the records count is  around  one million and I doubt this blow my JVM.